# Mixed content errors with https?

Tags: https, mixed-content

This one has me perplexed...

On my website, I am getting Mixed content errors in my console yet when inspecting the source, the urls it says are http are showing as https?

In fact, a search for anything with http:// returns nothing.

Inspection shows:

```
<img src="https://images.immoafrica.net/aHR0cHM6Ly9yZXZvbHV0aW9uY3JtLXJldm9sdXRpb24tcHJvcGltYWdlcy5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tLzU2LzE3MTk4OC8xMjcxOTk0X2xhcmdlLmpwZw==/fb5c609f3c1506a8798dfa620ccf8a15?1=1&amp;width=420&amp;height=310&amp;mode=crop&amp;scale=both&amp;404=default" data-lazy="https://images.immoafrica.net/aHR0cHM6Ly9yZXZvbHV0aW9uY3JtLXJldm9sdXRpb24tcHJvcGltYWdlcy5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tLzU2LzE3MTk4OC8xMjcxOTk0X2xhcmdlLmpwZw==/fb5c609f3c1506a8798dfa620ccf8a15?1=1&amp;width=420&amp;height=310&amp;mode=crop&amp;scale=both&amp;404=default" alt="2 Bedroom Apartment for Sale in Strand North" title="2 Bedroom Apartment for Sale in Strand North" class="lazy loading-F5F5F5">
```

Yet I get this error:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.immoafrica.net/residential/for-sale/south-africa/?advanced-search=1&st=' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://images.immoafrica.net/aHR0cHM6Ly9yZXZvbHV0aW9uY3JtLXJldm9sdXRpb24tcHJvcGltYWdlcy5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tLzU2LzE3MTk4OC8xMjcxOTk0X2xhcmdlLmpwZw==/fb5c609f3c1506a8798dfa620ccf8a15?1=1&width=420&height=310&mode=crop&scale=both&404=default'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is requesting the following `https` URL:

https://images.immoafrica.net/aHR0cHM6Ly9yZXZvbHV0aW9uY3JtLXJldm9sdXRpb24tcHJvcGltYWdlcy5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tLzU2LzE3MTk4OC8xMjcxOTk0X2xhcmdlLmpwZw==/fb5c609f3c1506a8798dfa620ccf8a15?1=1&width=420&height=310&mode=crop&scale=both&404=default

…but the server is redirecting that `https` URL to the following `http` URL:

http://images.immoafrica.net/aHR0cHM6Ly9yZXZvbHV0aW9uY3JtLXJldm9sdXRpb24tcHJvcGltYWdlcy5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tLzU2LzE3MTk4OC8xMjcxOTk0X2xhcmdlLmpwZw==/fb5c609f3c1506a8798dfa620ccf8a15?1=1&width=420&height=310&mode=crop&scale=both&404=default

Paste that `https` URL into your browser address bar and you’ll see you end up at the `http` URL.

Or try it from the command line with something like `curl`:

```
$ curl -i 'https://images.immoafrica.net/aHR0cHM6Ly9yZXZvbHV0aW9uY3JtLXJldm9sdXRpb24tcHJvcGltYWdlcy5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tLzU2LzE3MTk4OC8xMjcxOTk0X2xhcmdlLmpwZw==/fb5c609f3c1506a8798dfa620ccf8a15?1=1&width=420&height=310&mode=crop&scale=both&404=default'

HTTP/2 301
date: Sat, 06 Jan 2018 01:56:57 GMT
cache-control: max-age=3600
expires: Sat, 06 Jan 2018 02:56:57 GMT
location: http://images.immoafrica.net/aHR0cHM6Ly9yZXZvbHV0aW9uY3JtLXJldm9sdXRpb24tcHJvcGltYWdlcy5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tLzU2LzE3MTk4OC8xMjcxOTk0X2xhcmdlLmpwZw==/fb5c609f3c1506a8798dfa620ccf8a15?1=1&width=420&height=310&mode=crop&scale=both&404=default
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 3d8b1051cfbf84fc-HKG
```

…and notice th server sends back a `301` response and a `location` header with the `http` URL.

So the problem seems to be, that `images.immoafrica.net` site isn’t served over HTTPS/TLS and instead redirects all requests for `https` URLs to their `http` equivalents.

There’s nothing you can do on your end to fix that — other than creating or using some kind of HTTPS proxy through which you make the requests for `images.immoafrica.net` URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using https:// use //. This will stop mixed content issues.

Comment: Did you read the other answer? It has nothing to do with this